# How to efficiently draw vector curves on mobile devices?

Tags: android, mobile, vector

I was working on a vector based mobile app. First I've started using polygons to represent Curves. However, I was reaching quickly the Polygon Limit on mobile phones. To overcome this limit, I've started using a Texture and was coloring the pixels. Even though this was a pretty easy solution, I was limited by the max resolution of textures and operations.

The only promising thing I've found was OpenVG, but it seems like it is not very popular.

So how are vector drawing apps on mobile phones created? I was stunned by Adobe Illustrator mobile, which seems to be able to draw limitless curves/lines in vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method to allow vector based free form curve drawing is to use [Bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Bezier curves are constructed by interpolating values defined by a start point, an end point and any number of control points. This results in the ability to construct a free form curve from a set of as little as 3 cartesian points.

A benefit of this is that by only storing tthe point data representing the curve, you can then render the same curve at any scale without having to store the curve in a texture. Therefore you do not need to store hundreds of intermediate points to form small line segments to represent the same curve.

[Here are a number of sample code snippets](https://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.graphics.Path) that use the Path object in Android to construct free form vector curves.

If you have a very large number of curves to render to the canvas, you only need to store the point data defining the bezier curve. It is important that you only create the `Path` object once, and use the `reset` method to redefine the points each time you would like to draw a new curve. [Sample code to achieve this can be found here.](https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.graphics.Path/reset)

Comment: I know how Bezier curves work, but how efficient is Androids Path curve? Can I draw thousands of lines without hitting any memory limit? An example apps rather than snippets?

Comment: Path is a mutable object in Android. So using only one path object, you can load the defining point data for a bezier curve, render to canvas, reset the path object and load the new point data to the same path object. Therefore your application can render thousands of curves given that there is enough memory to store the point data to define all the bezier curves. Here are some examples of how you use reset to redefine the point data in a Path object so it can be reused: https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.graphics.Path/reset

Comment: All of the samples on the  codota page link to the github project they are part of so you can download a complete project that uses the code snippet.